# How to use the Generic where clause to check for Class Type that also has a Generic Type

Tags: c#, generics

I have an Entity class that is inherited by all sorts of different classes. In this Entity class I have a property called Identity that has it's type based on the TIdentity generic type. I am making another class that has a generic type for Entity, for example EntityCollection. I can not figure out how to set a where clause for the Entity class. I need that where clause for that specific class because I need access to that Identity property inside my EntityCollection class.

Here is the Entity class.

```cs
public abstract class Entity<TIdentity> where TIdentity : Identity, new()
{
    protected Entity()
    {
        Identity = new TIdentity();
    }

    public TIdentity Identity { get; protected set; }
}
```

Here is the Identity class:

```cs
public abstract class Identity
{
    protected Identity()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    protected Identity(Guid id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }

    public Guid Id { get; }
}
```

Here is a class that inherits Entity:

```cs
public class Example : Entity<ExampleId>
{
    public Example()
    {
    }

    //...Properties specific to this class. Not relevant to this question.
}
```

Here is a class that inherits Identity:

```cs
public class ExampleId : Identity
{
    public Example()
    {
    }

    public Example(Guid id) : base(id)
    {
    }
}
```

1st Attempt:

```cs
public class EntityCollection<TEntity> : CustomCollection<TEntity> where TEntity : Entity
{
    public EntityCollection(IEnumerable<TEntity> collection) : base(collection)
    {
        RemovedItems = new List<TEntity>();
    }

    private EntityCollection(IEnumerable<TEntity> collection, IEnumerable<TEntity> removedItems) : base(collection)
    {
        RemovedItems = removedItems;
    }

    public EntityCollection<TEntity, TIdentity> New(IEnumerable<TEntity> newCollection)
    {
        var newCollectionList = newCollection.ToList();
        var newCollectionIds = newCollectionList.Select(item => item.Identity).ToList();
        var removedItems = new List<TEntity>();

        foreach (var item in Collection)
        {
            if (!newCollectionIds.Contains(item.Identity))
            {
                removedItems.Add(item);
            }
        }

        return new EntityCollection<TEntity, TIdentity>(newCollectionList, removedItems);
    }
}
```

This barks at me saying "Using the generic type 'Entity' requires 1 type argument." So 1st attempt failed.

2nd Attempt:

```cs
public class EntityCollection<TEntity, TIdentity> : CustomCollection<TEntity> 
    where TIdentity : Identity, new() 
    where TEntity : Entity<TIdentity>
{
    public EntityCollection(IEnumerable<TEntity> collection) : base(collection)
    {
        RemovedItems = new List<TEntity>();
    }

    private EntityCollection(IEnumerable<TEntity> collection, IEnumerable<TEntity> removedItems) : base(collection)
    {
        RemovedItems = removedItems;
    }

    public EntityCollection<TEntity, TIdentity> New(IEnumerable<TEntity> newCollection)
    {
        var newCollectionList = newCollection.ToList();
        var newCollectionIds = newCollectionList.Select(item => item.Identity).ToList();
        var removedItems = new List<TEntity>();

        foreach (var item in Collection)
        {
            if (!newCollectionIds.Contains(item.Identity))
            {
                removedItems.Add(item);
            }
        }

        return new EntityCollection<TEntity, TIdentity>(newCollectionList, removedItems);
    }
}
```

This worked as I hoped. The only issue here is I don't really want to have to say the TIdentity, because the Entity is already defining that

For now I have gone with my 2nd attempt solution. But if anyone out there has  a better solution then by all means, please share your answer. I will update this post if I have found a better solution.

Comment: Show your "logic", this is very important part here :)

Comment: "_The only issue here is I don't really want to have to say the TIdentity, because the Entity is already defining that_". No, you confuse something. You define a type constraint there in your EntityCollection<TEntity, TIdentity> class. How should the constraint know what TIdentity is if you don't define it for the constraint? Note that the constraints describes/decides which types are applicable as the TEntity parameter Your Example class is not a constraint, it is just a class implementing Entity<ExampleID>. (The mere existence of a class does not make it a type constraint.)

Comment: This tends to get really confusing, especially if we're starting out with generic base classes. If you've got something that compiles that's good. But sometimes it's helpful to create some of the classes we need without all the generic base classes, write a little bit of code that uses them, and then maybe refactor into base classes when we see what the "finished" classes have in common. Otherwise we risk laying the foundation and then finding out that it doesn't match what we try to build on it.

Comment: There let me know if that's better

Comment: Edited it again one more time. Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly sensible but sadly this is not yet supported. It is called *higher kinded parametric polymorphism*. [Roslyn feature](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/2212)